# Invalid selected rows in onExecute() of SPFX ListView Command set

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

Simple code just built from `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` wizard:

**Elements.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="HelloWorld"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
        ClientSideComponentId="4dce5cb5-8742-49af-9e0b-2cf03ebaafb8"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;sampleTextOne&quot;:&quot;One item is selected in the list.&quot;, &quot;sampleTextTwo&quot;:&quot;This command is always visible.&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
```

Extension manifest json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/command-set-extension-manifest.schema.json",

  "id": "4dce5cb5-8742-49af-9e0b-2cf03ebaafb8",
  "alias": "HelloWorldCommandSet",
  "componentType": "Extension",
  "extensionType": "ListViewCommandSet",

  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,
  "requiresCustomScript": false,

  "items": {
    "COMMAND_1": {
      "title": { "default": "Command One" },
      "type": "command"
    },
    "COMMAND_2": {
      "title": { "default": "Command Two" },
      "type": "command"
    }
  }
}
```

Extension implementation (`onExecute`, `import { RowAccessor } from '@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility';` should be appended, other code places are not changed):

```
  @override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    const selectedRow: RowAccessor = event.selectedRows[0];

    const leafName: string = selectedRow.getValueByName('FileLeafRef');
    const name: string = selectedRow.getValueByName('FileRef');
    const id: string = selectedRow.getValueByName('ID');
    const fields: string = JSON.stringify(selectedRow.fields);

    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        Dialog.alert(`Leaf: ${leafName}. Name: ${name}. Id: ${id}. Fields: ${fields}`);
        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':
        alert(`Leaf: ${leafName}. Name: ${name}. Id: ${id}. Fields: ${fields}`);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }
```

So it's ListView Command Set extension that works with library (RegistrationId="101") and has two commands. When some command is executed it shows some information of selected item from list view.

But while you're selecting items one by one in list `onExecute` receives data of item that was selected the first.
Example:

1. Select file "Map 1 (6).xslx". Handler `onExecute` has received correct selection data.
   [image: correct]
2. Close alert and select the next file "Test0.mmap", but handler `onExecute` still receives data about "Map 1 (6).xslx" file.
   [image]
   How to fix this bug? Looks like extension doesn't receive information about selection changes.

**Workaround 1:** If user clears selection after step 1 and selects "Test0.mmap" after clearing, everything works fine. But it's not solution.
Bug exists in SP Online only, SP 2019 works fine in this scenario.

**Workaround 2:** If commands registered for both ContextMenu and CommandBar, bug doesn't exist. But I need context menu commands only.

Comment: Looks like it's bug in SP Online - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4769

Comment: I noticed the same bug with custom list and wasn't able to find a proper fix for it. My workaround was to refresh the whole page after the dialog box closes. That was the only way to be sure that users would execute the command on the item they really wanted.

Comment: @DamjanTomic, yep, SPFX has two similar bug https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4828 and https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4769. They completely destroy listview command functionality.